# GAS: Can you use searchFiles on a searchFiles result?

Tags: google-apps-script, logic

This question might be more of a logical problem than a function problem.

I have two sets of PDFs "bought" and "return".
I use this to search for them:

```
qsBought = "fullText contains 'Bought' and mimeType='" + MimeType.PDF + "'";
qsReturn = "fullText contains 'Return' and mimeType='" + MimeType.PDF + "'";
```

Every file also have one device type in them. i.e. computer, chromebook, mac or iPad:

I can search for this with:

```
qsComputer = "fullText contains 'Computer' and mimeType='" + MimeType.PDF + "'";
```

I then use this to save the search result into a variable.

```
myFiles = parentFolder.searchFiles(qsXxx)
```

The result is then pushed to a sheet (that works like a I expect).

```
  while(myFiles.hasNext()) {
    var file, fileName, s, t;
    file = myFiles.next();
    fileName = file.getName();
    s = fileName.substr(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.')) || fileName;
    t = s.split(' - ');
  push(output, t, dv, qs);
 }
```

- output = colum headers
- t = the name of the filename split
- dv = supposed to be the device
- qs = bought/returned

On every line I want to push out the information about if the devices is returned or bought.

I'm think that I can do a searchFiles(device) on the previous searchFiles(bought/returned) to find all computers bought, then computers returned, chromebooks bought and so on...

I've tried

```
qsBoughtComputer = "fullText contains 'Bought' and fullText contains 'computer' and mimeType='" + MimeType.PDF + "'";
```

I don't think searchFiles() support multiple fullText queries in the same search.

I don't fully grasp the logic or how to work with only these functions. If possible, I prefer to work with Googles core functions and repositories (first-party).

Thankful for any help in this!

Comment: What makes you think that `DriveApp.searchFiles()` would not support multiple `fullText` queries in the same search? Try `"fullText contains 'Bought' and fullText contains 'Computer' and mimeType = '" + MimeType.PDF + "'"`.

Comment: Could you share the result that you are currently getting with the function?

Comment: @doubleunary you're right...the problem was that I didn't chance the rest of my functions to output my new values.

Comment: @GabrielCarballo the scripts would run, but I got the wrong output. Instead of having every device output on the line, I got whatever device (i.e. computer) on every line. Bc. I had a iteration formula that didn't do what I thought it would.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @doubleunary said in the comments.

Why would it not work?

I should've tried the solution after I made all the necessary changes to the code...

As I stated in the beginning;

> This question might be more of a logical problem than a function
> problem.